# React native navigator consuming too much memory

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux, react-native-navigation

I'm building my first react native android project that has a nested navigation of the scenes. My current code is working, however it seems that the memory is suffering a lot. Please see attached illustration of the problem. I used the navigator.push() on "Visit related product button" and navigator.pop() for back button.

Illustration on how to reproduce the problem:
[image: Illustration on how to reproduce the problem]

Is there anyone knows the solution on this?

Comment: Rather include the image in the question.

Comment: Hi Morgoth here's the image, any idea on how to solve that problem?

Comment: Did you solve it?